# consumer surplus in r

Tags: r, economics

I'm trying to do some econometric analysis using R and can't figure out how to do the analysis I'm look for. Specifically, I want to calculate consumer surplus.
I am trying to predict number of trips (dependent) based on variables like water quality, scenery, parking, etc. I've run a regression of my independent variables on my dependent variable using:

```
lm()
```

and also got my predicted values using:

```
y_hat <- as.matrix(mydata[c("y")])
```

Now I want to calculate the consumer surplus for each individual (~260 total) from my predicted (`y_hat`) values.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is related to economics: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61732/economics

Comment: I agree @Metrics insomuch as the help goes beyond R programming itself.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to R. I studied economics in college and wish R was taught. You will find that the programming language is very useful in your work.

Note that R is able to accomplish vectorized operations that may speed up your analysis. Consider:

```
mydata <- data.frame(x=letters[1:3], y=1:3)
  x y
1 a 1
2 b 2
3 c 3
```

Let's say your predicted 'y' is 1.25.

```
y_hat <- 1.25
```

You can subtract that number by the entire column of the dataset and it will go row by row for you without having to use compicated 'for loops.'

```
y_hat - mydata[c("y")]
      y
1  0.25
2 -0.75
3 -1.75
```

Without more information about your particular issue, that is all the help that I can offer. In the future, add a reproducible example that illustrates your data and the specific issue that you are stuck on.

Comment: Are you saying `y_hat - mydata[c("y")]` is the consumer surplus?

Comment: No. Just that vectorized operations are possible. A lesson on consumer surplus is beyond the scope of this forum.